# Customized Custom Google Search API

Tags: google-api

We actually just need the **number** of search results from google.
However, the Custom Search API is an overkill, and we are just limited for 100 searches per day.
We could resort to scraping but are worried that it might ban us...

Is there any way we could get what we need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google have a [AJAX Search API](https://developers.google.com/products/?hl=tr) with this [example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#large_result_set) Number of Search Results

Comment: The problem with this is that the results are not actually the same as the results on google search. Are we not limited to the number of queries as 100?